# How to count MySQL results in a has-many-through relation

Tags: mysql, sql, count, has-many, relational-division

There is pretty good article how to filter results in a has-many relation:
**[How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)**

I'm just seeking a solution for COUNT result, not show them all.

```
student {
    id
    name
}
club {
    id
    name
}
student_club {
    student_id
    club_id
}
```

**How many students are in both CLUB1 && CLUB2?**

**EDIT:**
It would be great to use **"Martin 2"** method from a link below:

```
SELECT s.stud_id, s.name
FROM   student s
JOIN   student_club sc USING (stud_id)
WHERE  sc.club_id IN (30, 50)
GROUP  BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Just adding something to COUNT results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query uses table aliases for tables `student_club` and `club`. This allows to return rows only for students who are in both clubs. Then, using `COUNT` allows to return the number of students:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM student s, student_club sc1, club c1, student_club sc2, club c2
WHERE s.id=sc1.student_id AND sc1.club_id=c1.id AND c1.name="CLUB1"
AND s.id=sc2.student_id AND sc2.club_id=c2.id AND c2.name="CLUB2"
```

If you really want to use the "Martin 2" query, you may count the number of records this way:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS nb
FROM (
    SELECT s.stud_id, s.name
    FROM   student s
    JOIN   student_club sc USING (stud_id)
    WHERE  sc.club_id IN (30, 50)
    GROUP  BY 1,2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) tmp;
```

Comment: CLUB1 and CLUB2 wath just examples. it can be 3 or more and more.
it would be great to use "Martin 2" method and count results.

Comment: Please don't change your question once it has been answered! Your current question is "How many students are in both CLUB1 && CLUB2?", and my answer solves this question.

Comment: Sorry, if i didn't explain it right, but for me it's not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Probably simplest, cleanest and fastest *for just two students*:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM   student_club x
JOIN   student_club y USING (stud_id)
WHERE  x.club_id = 30
AND    y.club_id = 50;
```

You don't need to join to the `student` table for this at all - as soon as you know the list of `stud_id` you are interested in.

For *any number of students*, Martin's query is more convenient. You can simplify in a similar fashion:

```
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM (
   SELECT stud_id
   FROM   student_club
   WHERE  club_id IN (30, 50)
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(*) = 2 -- adapt to number of items in list
   ) x;
```

Requires that `(stud_id, club_id)` is unique of course, and that list items are also unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it really simplifies.

Comment: Can you explain what means "x" at last of the query?

Comment: @IkaPkhakadze: That's short for `AS x` and is the alias for the subquery. Every subquery in the FROM list needs a name in SQL.